# Align lines when longer than one

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items on subnav as in below...

[image]

And The html for each of the codes is as below

```
<label for="DOG - BARK CONTROL TRAINING &amp; BEHAVIOURAL_searchSubCategories" class="facet_block-label"><span>DOG - BARK CONTROL TRAINING &amp; BEHAVIOURAL (2)</span>                         </label>
```

And the css is as below

```
label {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

label span {
    float: none;
    position: inherit;
    width: auto;
}
```

The problem is when lines are longer then rather than aligning properly it is not doing so. For instance I want the word behavioural (2) to align nicely with dog.. Any idea how to do it easily with css?

Comment: Slightly off topic, do you know that the value for the attribute `for` needs to be the same as your input `id` ? e.g `<label for="input1">Dog</label> <input id="input1">`

Comment: Thanks.. didnt notice that.. fixing it now.. But the problem still is there :) Any solution

Answer (score 2):

Solution is to change `display` of the label to `inline-block`
Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdEmH/23/).